# Removal of cursor which is processing bad data

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, try-catch

How can we remove cursor in the following scenario:

```
DECLARE @Tablesq TABLE (numbercol INT)
INSERT INTO @Tablesq
SELECT 25 UNION all
SELECT -25 UNION all
SELECT 25 UNION all
SELECT 36

DECLARE @number INT

DECLARE sqrtcur CURSOR  FOR SELECT numbercol FROM @tablesq
OPEN sqrtcur
FETCH NEXT FROM sqrtcur INTO @number
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
         BEGIN TRY
         SELECT SQRT(@number)
         END TRY
         BEGIN CATCH
                print ERROR_MESSAGE();
         END CATCH
         FETCH NEXT FROM sqrtcur INTO @number
   END

CLOSE sqrtcur
DEALLOCATE sqrtcur
```

Here -25 value is causing the error and because of which I am forced to use the cursor. Can we do a set-based operation to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not provide very good error handling within a `SELECT` statement.  The one exception is for type conversion and the `try_` functions -- but even that is relatively recently in the history of the database.

SQL is not alone in this.  The standard just does not address this point.

The one thing you can do is use a `case` expression, if you understand the conditions when you will get an error:

```
select (case when numbercol >= 0 then sqrt(numbercol) end)
from tablesq;
```

SQL Server guarantees that the `when` conditions are evaluated in order, stopping at the first match, and the `then` is evaluated after then `when`.  I should say "under almost all circumstances"; there are some optimizations made in aggregation queries that somewhat weaken that statement.

Many other databases have similar limitations.  And in most of them, you can use a user-defined function that catches the exception.  Alas, SQL Server does not allow `try`/`catch` blocks in UDFs, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT SQRT(numbercol)
FROM @Tablesq
WHERE numbercol > 0;
```

Comment: sqrt() function is just representative here...there could be any function which may cause the error because of data and in that case how to handle the situation without cursor

Comment: Well it depends on the case as different function have different requirements. The best thing to do is to try to filter the `wrong` data - this can be done using filtering `WHERE` clauses, `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT` - if the function needs particular value type or `CASE WHEN`/`IFF` to execute the functions only if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
DECLARE @tablesq TABLE (numbercol INT)
INSERT INTO @tablesq
SELECT 25 UNION all
SELECT -25 UNION all
SELECT 25 UNION all
SELECT 36;

DECLARE @number INT;

DECLARE sqrtcur CURSOR  FOR SELECT numbercol FROM @tablesq;
DECLARE @TEST FLOAT;
OPEN sqrtcur;
FETCH NEXT FROM sqrtcur INTO @number;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
         BEGIN TRY
            SET @TEST = SQRT(@number);
            SELECT SQRT(@number);
         END TRY
         BEGIN CATCH
                print ERROR_MESSAGE();
         END CATCH;
         FETCH NEXT FROM sqrtcur INTO @number;
   END;
CLOSE sqrtcur;
DEALLOCATE sqrtcur;
```